# Extract elements from a xml response in jmeter according to a specific string in the element

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, jmeter

[image][image][image]I want to extract the contents of SFDCProductList in a variable, which is an array.
How to do this?

I have this following xml:
    
       .
       .
       .
       `10000`
       Thank You! Your request has been successfully executed. Code PIM 10000
       
          
             sgfsuifg
             sjkfbksgfsudf

```
      </SFDCProduct>
   </SFDCProductList>
   <SFDCProductList>
   .
   .
   .
</SFDCProductList>
<SFDCProductList>
   .
   .
   .
</SFDCProductList>
   <TransportInformation>
   .
   .
   .
   </TransportInformation>
</EnhancedServicePrequalResponse>

<EnhancedServicePrequalResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Code>10000</Code>
<Message>Thank You!</Message>
<SFDCProductList>
<SFDCProduct>
<OfferName>XYZ</OfferName>
<OfferDisplayName>New Offer</OfferDisplayName>
<OfferType>New</OfferType>
<EndDate>2021-02-16</EndDate>
<OfferLineItemList>
<OfferLineItem>
<OfferLineItemCategory>Transport Service</OfferLineItemCategory>
<OfferLineItemName>transport</OfferLineItemName>
</OfferLineItem>
<OfferLineItem>
<OfferLineItemCategory>Device</OfferLineItemCategory>
<OfferLineItemName>Billing</OfferLineItemName>
</OfferLineItem>
</OfferLineItemList>
<TransportName>BR</TransportName>
</SFDCProduct>
</SFDCProductList>
<SFDCProductList>
<SFDCProduct>
<OfferName>Upgrade</OfferName>
<OfferDisplayName>Upgrade</OfferDisplayName>
<OfferType>Upgrade</OfferType>
<EndDate>2021-02-16</EndDate>
<OfferLineItemList>
<OfferLineItem>
<OfferLineItemCategory>Transport</OfferLineItemCategory>
<OfferLineItemName>Billing</OfferLineItemName>
</OfferLineItem>
<OfferLineItem>
<OfferLineItemCategory>Device</OfferLineItemCategory>
<OfferLineItemName>Billing</OfferLineItemName>
</OfferLineItem>
</OfferLineItemList>
<TransportName>JR</TransportName>
</SFDCProduct>
</SFDCProductList>
<TransportInformation>
<TransportFeasibilityParameter>
<AvailabilityFlag>true</AvailabilityFlag>
<BusinessAvailabilityFlag>true</BusinessAvailabilityFlag>
<TransportName>BR</TransportName>
</TransportFeasibilityParameter>
<TransportFeasibilityParameter>
<AvailabilityFlag>true</AvailabilityFlag>
<BusinessAvailabilityFlag>true</BusinessAvailabilityFlag>
<TransportName>JR/TransportName>
</TransportFeasibilityParameter>
</TransportInformation>
</EnhancedServicePrequalResponse>
```

I tried with xpath extractor but its not storing it in a variable.

I have successfully extracted the SFDCProductlist with Boundary extractor but as its an array i only want that SFDCProductlist which has "New" keyword in the element .

```
The beanshell Script:

int SFDCProduct_matchNr =vars.get("SFDCProduct_matchNr");

String list="SFDCProduct"+"_"+"SFDCProduct_matchNr";
int SFDCProduct_matchNrvalue=SFDCProduct_matchNr-1;
vars.put("SFDCProduct_matchNr", "SFDCProduct_matchNrvalue");
vars.put("sfdc", "list");enter code here

But still its not assigning the sfdc with SFDCProduct_1 value??
```

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: I have updated the actual payload.

Comment: With the simple xpath extractor i can get the total number of variables generated with this: SFDCProduct_matchNr. But i need to put a condition/loop which goes over these variables and if there is substring new then use that variable "SFDC_Product_1" in next steps.

Comment: I have used a while loop, then bean shell processor and a regular expression extractor. The while checks the number of the SFDCProduct_matchNr and whether the variable is set to NEw or not from Regex extractor. Beanshell assigns the new variable with the  SFDCProduct_i we want and the regular expression creates a variable which has the keyword New stored if in that variable NEw is present.  But some how its not going in to the while loop.??

Comment: The while condition is: ${__javaScript("${SFDCProduct_matchNr}" == -1 && "${SFDCProduct_NewOffer}" == "New",)}.

Comment: Thank you all for your solution. I have resolved till some extent. The last part I am posting as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract contents inside specific boundaries you can use [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor):

Choose  as Left boundary and `</SFDCProductList>` as Right boundary.

Put new variable name in `Name of created variable` as productList and use it later as `${productList}` or `vars.get("productList")` inside a JSR223 script.

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using left and right boundaries. As a post-processor, this element will execute after each Sample request in its scope, testing the boundaries, extracting the requested values, generate the template string, and store the result into the given variable name.
>   [image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I have successfully extracted the SFDCProductlist with Boundary extractor but as its an array i only want that SFDCProductlist which has "New" keyword in the element <OfferName>. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

From you response code, seems like there are more than one product list.

To fetch all, you need to set Match No. to -1 in the Boundary extractor. Then, use the vars.get{"Product_List_1"} to fetch specific one.

[image]

If you need all in one variable, one way, is to combine different array list.

With RegEx:-(.\d\n)
[image]

Comment: I have successfully extracted the SFDCProductlist with Boundary extractor but as its an array i only want that SFDCProductlist which has "New" keyword in the element <OfferName>. Is there a way regex and boundary can be joineD?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full XML response we cannot come up with an exact solution, however for [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) response types it makes sense to stick to [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

The relevant XPath query should be something like: `//SFDCProductList` - it will basically return everything under `<SFDCProductList>` tag:

[image: JMeter XPath Extractor Demo]

If it doesn't - double check your XPath expression using "XPath Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, in some cases you might need to:

1. Tick `Use Tidy` box if the response is not valid XML/XHTML
2. If there are [XML Namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) in the response you will either need to declare the namespaces using [xpath.namespace.config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#xml_parser) property or use functions like [name()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) or [local-name()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name) functions instead of tag names
3. In case of any troubles first of all check *jmeter.log* file - in the majority of cases it contains enough information to get to the bottom of the issue.

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)